# Python: Trouble With SKVideo

Tags: python, video-capture

I've included this line in a script I'm writing:

```
from skvideo.io import VideoCapture
```

My script doesn't like this and gives me back:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'VideoCapture'
```

However, when I go into the REPL for Python 3.6 (what I'm using to run my script), I can `import skvideo.io` just fine.  So the trouble lies with VideoCapture, I'm just not sure why it can't import it...

Any ideas?

Thanks!